# How to do a Select Case with Left function in VBA?

Tags: vba, case

I'm trying to do a `Select Case` with `Left` function (`contain(text in the cell)` would be better but I don't know how to do that) but wasn't able to figure out how to do that.

I tried the following:

```
Sub siteadd()
    Dim x
    Dim Pl
    Dim Li

    Sheets("ort").Select
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To NumRows
        Li = cells(x, 6).Value
        Pl = cells(x, 40).FormulaR1C1 = "=Left(RC[40], 12)"

        Select Case Li
            Case "#N/A"
                Select Case Pl
                    Case "asc aite Aad"
                        cells(x, 6).Value = "B"
                End Select
        End Select
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: SELECT CASE LEFT(Li, <no of characters from the left>). So, if the String Li="Hello world", SELECT CASE LEFT(Li, 4) would be evaluating "Hell".

Comment: thanks, I ended up using IF