# Find and replace items that start with "F*"

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I have rows in my Excel from `RowA` and `RowX`.

My intent is to find all items that start with "F" in ROWB and replace it with value 5 in ROWX, all others with have 31 in ROwX.

```
Sub ReplaceDashes()
    Dim Cmcode As String
    Dim Rownum As Long

    Rownum = 6

    With Range("B6")
        Do Until Cells(Rownum, 2).Value = ""
            Select Case Cells(Rownum, 2).Value
                Case Left(.Text, 1) = "F"
                    Cells(Rownum, 24).Value = "5"
                Case Else
                    Cells(Rownum, 24).Value = "31"
            End Select
            Rownum = Rownum + 1
        Loop
    End With

    MsgBox ("DONE")

End Sub
```

The above does not work the way I wanted, it does not work for the first case, it replaces everything with "31" . Can some one suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Found a solution. The select case has to be performed directly over left function:

```
Sub ReplaceDashes()

Dim Cmcode As String
Dim Rownum As Long
Dim mystr As String

Rownum = 6

With Cells(Rownum, 2)
    Do Until Cells(Rownum, 2).Value = ""
        mystr = Cells(Rownum, 2).Value
        Select Case Left(mystr, 1)
            Case "f"
                Cells(Rownum, 24).Value = "5"
            Case Else
                Cells(Rownum, 24).Value = "31"
        End Select
        Rownum = Rownum + 1
    Loop
End With

MsgBox ("DONE")
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Archana, please check the edited answer now. Credits here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574574/how-to-do-a-select-case-with-left-function-in-vba